# Is the following Javascript Execution Order correct?

Tags: javascript

Coding noob trying to understand JS.  I have the following simple code and trying to breakup in detail the correct execution order.

```
function b() {
    console.log(myVar)
}

function a() {
    var myVar = 2;
    b();
}

var myVar = 1;
a();
```

I tried to break it down as following

```
1.      Global Creation Phase started  where JS engine searches for all new variables and functions to be created..
        First search for all new variables sitting on the Global stage

2.      finds one variable called myVar
        creates window.myVar memory space and assigns "undefined" as its value
        window.myVar is NOT assigned 1 as its value at this stage!!!
        finds no more new variables to be created

3.      now searches for all new functions sitting on the Global stage to be allocated a memory space
        finds two functions b( ) and a( ) to be created

4.      it creates window.b( ) memory first since it lexically sits before a( )
        4.1     new local creation phase started
                searches for new variables
                it finds no new variables to be created
        4.2     it searches for new functions
                it finds no new functions to be created
        4.3     local execution phase started
                creates memory space for console.log using window.myVar value that it found from the Global stage which is at this moment is "undefined"
                it does not log the return value to the console yet....
        finish window.b( ) memory creation phase

5.          Start window.a( ) memory creation phase
        5.1     all new creation phase started
                searches for all new variables
                finds var myVar command and creates a.myVar memory space and assigns "undefined" as its value
                a.myVar is  NOT assigned the value 2 at this stage !!!
        5.2     searches for all new functions
                finds no new function
        5.3     local execution phase started
                runs window.b( ) and stores the whatever the return value of window.b( ) into the return value of window.a( ) memory...  which is to log "undefined" into the console
                it still does not log its return value to console 
        finish window.a() memory creation phase

6.      all local creation phase  local execution phase and Global creation phase finished

7.      Starts Global execution phase

8.      Finds myVar = 1 command and assigns value 1 to window.myVar 

9.      finds a( ) command and execute function window.a( )

10.     goes into window.a( ) function and assigns value 2 to a.myVar
        finds b( ) command and executes window.b( ) passing window.myVar's value of 1 since window.myVar is what the window.b() return value is waiting for...  not a.myVar value
        receives the command to log 1 into console from function window.b( ) and sends it back to window.a( ) return value 

11.     back to global stage: window.a( ) function receives the return value which is:  log 1 to the console 

12.     logs 1 to the console and finished....  phew!!!!
```

Can anyone comment on if this execution order is correct or not...  especially when are the variables value are assigned...  thanks...

Comment: 12 is executed before going back to `a()`. `b()` returns `undefined`

Comment: I think it's mostly correct. In 5.1 (and 4.1) you say it's looking for variables, I don't think this happens. The scope for a function isn't created until it's called. Each time you call a function you get a new scope. So there is not just one `a.myVar`, there can be many. These seperate scopes become important when you're dealing with closures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things I disagree with

- Before **2.** there are two more variables defined **a** and **b** of function type at global level.
- Also in **4.**  and **5.**, the respective *local creation phase* doesn't start untill they are invoked.